# How do i get the X number of unique items from an array

Tags: javascript

Im trying to change the X number in the for loop based on what array this function is using. The function gets x random values from an array which he then checks if it isnt the same value and if it isnt the same value he then returns the 2 random values in the array. i tried doing a switch statement like this:

```
switch(this) {
   case array1:
       x = 2;
       break;
   case array2:
       x = 3;
       break;
}
```

code

```
Array.prototype.random = function () {
    let result = [];
    let bool = false;
    let x = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        result.push(this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)]);
    }
    while (bool == false) {
        if (result[0] === result[1]) {
            result.pop();
            result.push(this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)]);
        } else {
            bool = true;
        }
    }
    return result[0] + "  +  " + result[1];
}
```

Comment: but `x` is initialized as `0`, your for loop will never run since `i` is never less (`<`) than `x`

Comment: Yeah i know about that, i tried using a switch statement and to check for an array but it wouldnt work out

Comment: do you have an example of wanted result?

Comment: Maybe `x` should be a function parameter, so the caller can specify how many items they want?

Comment: You seem to be missing a `*` before `this.length`

Comment: Please edit the question and explain what this function is supposed to do.

Comment: Why do you need the `result` array? It looks like you just need to create one random number, then create another random number in a loop until it's different from the first one. Then return the two random numbers.

Comment: edited the question for you, hopefully its a bit clearer now

Answer (score 1):

Getting the amount of unique items in the array looks something like

```js
function getUniqueCount(list){
  let storage={}, count=0;
  for(let i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    if(!storage[list[i]]){
      storage[list[i]]=true; count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

But I'm not sure if that number would help you because you're not saying what you want your function to do

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the `x` variable is supposed to be. If you just want to return 2 random elements from the array, there's no need for that variable or the `result` array. Just use two variables.

```js
Array.prototype.random = function() {
  let item1 = this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
  while (true) {
    let item2 = this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
    if (item2 != item1) {
      return item1 + "  +  " + item2;
    }
  }
}

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].random());
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove "()this" because this is a syntax error.

You're trying to do a math calculation:

```
Math.random() * this.length
```

Not a syntax error:

```
Math.random()this.length
```

And also, you're for loop is not doing anything, because `i` counts up to `x` only if `i` is lower than `x`. But `i` and `x` are both 0, so it will not do anything. If you're trying to make the for loop go up 1 time, just use "2", for 2 results instead of "0".

Next, `result.pop()` is just returning the value of "result" popped.

Remove that.

Comment: That's just a typo, it doesn't deserve a real answer.

Comment: Why do you need a loop if it just runs one time?

Comment: I have no clue why but i had the `*` in my code, but it didnt show up when i copy pasted it here

Comment: Not really, but if you want to return the value of "i", in the loop, it could do something. It doesn't mean it's useful

Comment: @Moosike at meta stackexchange, someone has a discussion about non-visible characters, it could be a bug or that.

Comment: ah, alright thanks for letting me know

Comment: Thanks for telling the mistake, I'll let stackexchange know about the bug.

Comment: `x` needs to be at least 2, because the following code expects `result` to contain 2 elements.